# how to connect nodes reading from csv file?

Tags: python

I have node list information with their correlation. I want to build the network by adding the nodes one by one. Here is my node information :

```
 (149, 88)
 (139, 168)
 (215, 218)
 (218, 215)
 (429, 400)
 (400, 429)
 (207, 176)
 (176, 207)
 (31, 45)
 (45, 31)
 (411, 381)
 (381, 411)
 (393, 335)
 (335, 393)
 (287, 317)
 (317, 287)
 (41, 77)
 (98, 130)
 (370, 340)
 ...
```

I am trying

```
  G.add_edge(149, 88)
  G.add_edge(139, 168)
  G.add_edge(215, 218)
  G.add_edge(218, 215)
  G.add_edge(429, 400)
  G.add_edge(400, 429)
  G.add_edge(207, 176) 
  G.add_edge(176, 207)
  G.add_edge(31, 45)
  G.add_edge(45, 31)
  G.add_edge(411, 381)
  G.add_edge(381, 411)
  G.add_edge(393, 335)
  G.add_edge(335, 393)
  G.add_edge(287, 317)
  G.add_edge(317, 287)
  G.add_edge(41, 77)
  ...
```

but I have more than 30000 nodes information, which is impossible to add  manually one by one.

Any clue how to do that by comment? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
for i in open('filename.csv'):
   G.add_edge(*ast.literal_eval(i.strip('\n')))
```